# mysql: whoami?

Tags: mysql

Is there a `whoami`-like function in mysql?

I'm connecting to the mysql command line from a remote host. I'm not sure if my ip address is resolving to a domain name or not. I would like to see something like

```
mysql> whoami;
+----------------------------------+
| User     | Host                  |
+----------------------------------+
| username | resolved.hostname.com |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

or

```
mysql> whoami;
+------------------------+
| User     | Host        |
+------------------------+
| username | 22.66.88.44 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use the `CURRENT_USER` and `USER` functions as follows:

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();

SELECT USER();
```

`CURRENT_USER` shows who you *are* authenticated as, while `USER` shows who you *tried to* authenticate as.

See [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) for more information.

Comment: Good catch, and you are of course right. Answer is updated now.

Comment: When would `USER` ever be different from `CURRENT_USER`? It seems that if they were different, you would have had to have failed authentication, which in that case, how would you issue the command in the first place?

Comment: There are several cases, documented by the MySQL manual in the link in the answer. You could end up being authenticated as an anonymous user although you specified a user, in which case `USER()` will return what you authenticated as while `CURRENT_USER()` will return an anonymous account (i.e. empty username). Also, within stored procedures, `CURRENT_USER()` will return the user who created the SP, or the invoker if defined with a `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` characteristic. In triggers and events, `CURRENT_USER()` always returns the user who created the object.

Answer (score 36):

If you are using `mysql` command line utility then try `\s` command:

```
mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.67, for suse-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.2

Connection id:          519
Current database:
Current user:           admin@localhost
.........
Server version:         5.0.67 SUSE MySQL RPM
.........
```

Answer (score -9):

Just do a...

```
select user,host from mysql.user;
```

Should show you what you want.