# Check the current user in MySQL command line

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

Here is my question about MySQL.

After I log in to MySQL using:

```
mysql -u myname -p
...
mysql>
```

I wanted to know what the username I used to logon. Is there a way to check this? like "whoami" in unix?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to know your current username in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350275/is-there-a-way-to-know-your-current-username-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql: whoami?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766359/mysql-whoami)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is a MYSQL function `user()`. 
To get the user:

```
SELECT USER();
```

This will return something like username@hostname.

Comment: mysql> STATUS; will list all info, if you need to do this from console.
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-version.html)

Comment: Please update the URL which u have added.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the current user with [CURRENT_USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user), [CURRENT_USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) or [USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user) as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350275/show-the-current-username-in-mysql/77461300#77461300) also explains the difference between `CURRENT_USER()` or `CURRENT_USER` and `USER()`:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT USER();
```